# CakePHP 2 with CakeDC/I18n language prefix being lost

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakedc

I have a CakePHP 2.5 site running with CakeDC/I18n plugin to allow for multi language support.  I have installed the plugin to use a 3 letter prefix when switching languages:

www.example.com/eng/

This is working fine when I click a button to change languages.  The language prefix is added to the url.  The problem is when I switch pages by clicking on a link the prefix is dropped.  Why would this be happening?  Do I need to do something in the href markup?  My understanding is that the CakeDC/I18n plugin would take care of this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been scratching my head with this one for awhile!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass as parameter the current language.

Otherwise it'll always use the default language that you defined in the bootstrap.php

Here is an example.

```
Router::url(
    'lang' => 'spa',
    'controller' => 'articles',
    'action' => 'view',
    'slug' => 'test'
);
```